# Facebook API - Posting as self on page I admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to support the ability to post to to a Facebook page as both the user and as the page itself.

As the user, I'm calling the following:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/feed 

message=test&access_token=<user_access_token>&format=json
```

As the page, I'm invoking the same call, except the access_token is the token returned for that page by me/accounts.

In both cases, the post is made by the page.

Is there a way using the API to post as my user to a page I administer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See 'Actor name will always match the access token' on the [Facebook Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/) - this is a migration to resolve the inconsistency you're encountering here.

Using the User access token of a Page admin can still cause the post to be made as the page depending on what that user has selected in the page management settings on facebook.com - there's an option to 'Always post as  even when logged in as '

Enabling that migration causes the post to always be from the owner of the access token (i.e page access token posts as the page, user access token posts as the user)

Comment: Thanks.  I actually had to search for that topic, and found it here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/08/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Comment: FWIW, I tried testing my calls with the 'Always post as even when logged in as' option both enabled and disabled, and results were the same both ways.

Comment: I think things like that are part of why that migration exists, it didn't quite make sense